# running a command in Ubuntu by runuser while the command has space

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I want to run a command by a specific user in Ubuntu (16.04) when I have root access using:

```
sudo runuser -u myuser 'mkdir a'
```

but I receive this error:

```
runuser: failed to execute mkdir a: No such file or directory
```

I got the same error for all other commands that have a space. However, for a command like this:

```
sudo runuser -u myuser 'ls'
```

It works fine. Is there any suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is

```
runuser -u user command argument
```

The argument to the command should be a separate argument to `runuser` as well.

```
sudo runuser -u myuser mkdir a
```

But if you're using `sudo`, you don't also need `runuser`.

```
sudo -u myuser mkdir a
```