# Running a single mysql command with the 'runuser' command

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb, sudo

For some strange reason, I can't find a way to make the runuser command work. I know it is possible to achieve this with `sudo -u mysql mysql -e "$DB_SETUP` but since I want to do this inside a script that already runs with `sudo` I find this not very pretty.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```bash
DB_SETUP="CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS $DB_USER@$BASEURL IDENTIFIED BY '$DB_PASSWORD';CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DB_NAME;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $DB_NAME.* TO $DB_USER@$BASEURL IDENTIFIED BY '$DB_PASSWORD';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
sudo runuser -u mysql "mysql -e \"$DB_SETUP\"" # does not work
```

It gives me this error:

```bash
runuser: failed to execute mysql -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS db_user@baseurl IDENTIFIED BY 'db_password';CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO db_user@baseurl IDENTIFIED BY 'password';": No such file or directory
```

Comment: `mysql -e <<< "$DB_SETUP"` maybe...

Comment: `runuser` expects the command to be in quotes. So this does not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: So the above is not quite right as I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948993/20733074). I got it working with this: `sudo runuser -u mysql mysql <<< $DB_SETUP`. So no quotes at all in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, I got it working with:

`sudo runuser -u mysql mysql <<< $DB_SETUP`

**No quotation marks at all!**